# Appcelerator Titanium - Horizontal scroll in Table Row

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have a table that I want to have horizontally scrolling rows.  When I tried adding a scrollable view to a row, it crashed the app.  Is there a particular way to do this? Basically, I'm adding items to each row dynamically and if it overflows I want the older items to scroll off the left, but still be retrievable.

Comment: I am having this problem too.  Did you find a solution to fit a scrollable into a table row?

Answer (score 3):

dont add a scroll view just use a regular view and update the width as items are added and scroll the view yourself.

you will have to figure out how scroll the view to the left and right by tracking touch start and touch end.

you might want to find an alternate UI approach though

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use layout property... i mean vertical or horizontal.

```
var HZview = Ti.UI.createView({
   height:'auto',
   layout:'horizontal'
)};

VzView.add(TableViewRows);
```

Now add your rows to this horizontal view and finally your TableView to Vertical View.

```
var HZview = Ti.UI.createView({
   height:'auto',
   layout:'vertical'
)};

VzView.add(TableView);
```